# Brezis' proposition 8.18: how to prove that $u^{\prime}(0)=\alpha$ and $u^{\prime}(1)=\beta$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation, sobolev-spaces, boundary-value-problem

I'm reading the proof of *Proposition 8.18.* in Brezis' *Functional Analysis* where I have a problem understanding how $u^{\prime}(0)=\alpha$ and $u^{\prime}(1)=\beta$.

---

**Example 3** (homogeneous Neumann condition). Consider the problem
$$
(21) \quad
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
-u^{\prime \prime}+u=f \quad \text { on } I=(0,1), \\
u^{\prime}(0)=u^{\prime}(1)=0
\end{array}\right.
$$

**Proposition 8.17.** Given $f \in L^2(I)$ there exists a unique function $u \in H^2(I)$ satisfying (21). Furthermore, $u$ is obtained by
$$
\min _{v \in H^1(I)}\left\{\frac{1}{2} \int_I\left(v^{\prime 2}+v^2\right)-\int_I f v\right\} .
$$
If, in addition, $f \in C(\bar{I})$, then $u \in C^2(\bar{I})$.

**Proof.** If $u$ is a classical solution of (21) we have
$$
(22) \quad
\int_I u^{\prime} v^{\prime}+\int_I u v=\int_I f v \quad \forall v \in H^1(I) .
$$

We use $H^1(I)$ as our function space: there is no point in working in $H_0^1$ as above since $u(0)$ and $u(1)$ are a priori unknown. We apply the Lax-Milgram theorem with the bilinear form $a(u, v)=\int_I u^{\prime} v^{\prime}+\int_I u v$ and the linear functional $\varphi: v \mapsto \int_I f v$. In this way we obtain a unique function $u \in H^1(I)$ satisfying (22). From (22) it follows, as above, that $u \in H^2(I)$. Using (22) once more we obtain
$$
(23) \quad
\int_I\left(-u^{\prime \prime}+u-f\right) v+u^{\prime}(1) v(1)-u^{\prime}(0) v(0)=0 \quad \forall v \in H^1(I) .
$$

In (23) begin by choosing $v \in H_0^1$ and obtain $-u^{\prime \prime}+u=f$ a.e. Returning to (23), there remains
$$
u^{\prime}(1) v(1)-u^{\prime}(0) v(0)=0 \quad \forall v \in H^1(I) .
$$
Since $v(0)$ and $v(1)$ are arbitrary, we deduce that $u^{\prime}(0)=u^{\prime}(1)=0$.

**Example 4** (inhomogeneous Neumann condition). Consider the problem
$$
(24) \quad
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
-u^{\prime \prime}+u=f \quad \text { on } I=(0,1), \\
u^{\prime}(0)=\alpha, u^{\prime}(1)=\beta,
\end{array}\right.
$$
with $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ given and $f$ a given function.

**Proposition 8.18.** Given any $f \in L^2(I)$ and $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists a unique function $u \in H^2(I)$ satisfying (24). Furthermore, $u$ is obtained by
$$
\min _{v \in H^1(I)}\left\{\frac{1}{2} \int_I\left(v^{\prime 2}+v^2\right)-\int_I f v+\alpha v(0)-\beta v(1)\right\} .
$$

If, in addition, $f \in C(\bar{I})$ then $u \in C^2(\bar{I})$.

**Proof.** If $u$ is a classical solution of (24) we have
$$
(25) \quad
\int_I u^{\prime} v^{\prime}+\int_I u v=\int_I f v-\alpha v(0)+\beta v(1) \quad \forall v \in H^1(I) .
$$

We use $H^1(I)$ as our function space and we apply the Lax-Milgram theorem with the bilinear form $a(u, v)=\int_I u^{\prime} v^{\prime}+\int_I u v$ and the linear functional
$$
\varphi: v \mapsto \int_I f v-\alpha v(0)+\beta v(1) .
$$

This linear functional is continuous (by Theorem 8.8). Then proceed as in **Example 3** to prove that $u \in H^2(I)$ and that $u^{\prime}(0)=\alpha, u^{\prime}(1)=\beta$.

---

**My attempt** If $u$ is a classical solution of (24) we have
$$
-\int_I u^{\prime \prime} v + \int_I u v=\int_I f v \quad \forall v \in H^1(I) .
$$

By integration by parts,
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_I u^{\prime \prime} v &= (u'v)(1)- (u'v)(0) - \int_I u^{\prime} v^{\prime} \\
&= \beta v(1)-  \alpha v (0) - \int_I u^{\prime} v^{\prime}.
\end{align*}
$$

Then we have $(25)$ and in particular,
$$
(26) \quad
\int_I u^{\prime} v^{\prime}+\int_I u v=\int_I f v
\quad \forall v \in H^1_0(I) .
$$

By integration by parts again,
$$
\int_I u^{\prime \prime} v =  - \int_I u^{\prime} v^{\prime} 
\quad \forall v \in H^1_0(I) .
$$

Then
$$
(27) \quad
\int_I (-u^{\prime \prime} + u^\prime-f)  v
\quad \forall v \in H^1_0(I) .
$$

Then $-u^{\prime \prime} + u^\prime=f$ a.e. on $I$. It follows from $(26)$ that $u' \in H^1 (I)$ with $u''=f-u$. Then $u \in H^2 (I)$.

> Could you explain how $u^{\prime}(0)=\alpha$ and $u^{\prime}(1)=\beta$?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: It looks like you swap between $H^1$ and $H_0^1$ somewhere. Double check this, as compactly supported test functions will eliminate boundary conditions from the weak form.

Comment: @whpowell96 I swapped between $H^1$ and $H^1_0$ in the equality $(26)$. However, I don't know how to get $u^{\prime}(0)=\alpha$ and $u^{\prime}(1)=\beta$. Could you elaborate on this point?

Comment: If $u\in H^2$ then you can revert the partial integration that lead to (25)

Comment: @daw Thank you so much for your help! I have formulated your idea as an answer posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $u$ is a classical solution of (24) we have
$$
-\int_I u^{\prime \prime} v + \int_I u v=\int_I f v,
\quad v \in H^1(I).
$$

By integration by parts (I.b.P),
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_I u^{\prime \prime} v &= (u'v)(1)- (u'v)(0) - \int_I u^{\prime} v^{\prime} \\
&= \beta v(1)-  \alpha v (0) - \int_I u^{\prime} v^{\prime},
\quad v \in H^1(I).
\end{align*}
$$

Then we have
$$
(25) \quad
\int_I u^{\prime} v^{\prime}+\int_I u v=\int_I f v + \beta v(1)-\alpha v(0),
\quad v \in H^1(I) .
$$

By Lax-Milgram theorem, there is a unique $u \in H^1$ that satisfies $(25)$. In particular,
$$
(26) \quad
\int_I u^{\prime} v^{\prime}+\int_I u v=\int_I f v,
\quad v \in H^1_0(I) .
$$
and
$$
(27) \quad
\int_I u^{\prime} \varphi^{\prime} = \int_I \varphi(f-u),
\quad \varphi \in C^1_c (I) .
$$

Clearly, $(27)$ implies $u \in H^2$ with $u'' =f-u$. By I.b.P,
$$
(28) \quad
 \int_I u^{\prime} v^{\prime} = - \int_I u^{\prime \prime} v,
\quad v \in H^1_0(I) .
$$

We have $(26, 28)$ implies
$$
(29) \quad
\int_I (-u^{\prime \prime} + u-f)  v,
\quad v \in H^1_0(I),
$$
and thus $-u^{\prime \prime} + u=f$ a.e. on $I$. Because $u' \in H^1$, we apply I.b.P and get
$$
(30) \quad
 \int_I u^{\prime \prime} v = (u'v) (1) - (u'v) (0) - \int_I u^{\prime} v^{\prime},
\quad v \in H^1 (I) .
$$

We have $(25, 30)$ and the fact that $-u^{\prime \prime} + u=f$ a.e. on $I$ imply
$$
\beta v (1) - \alpha v (0) = u' (1) v (1) - u'(0) v (0)
\quad v \in H^1 (I),
$$
and thus $\beta = u'(1)$ and $\alpha = u' (0)$. This completes the proof.